# Image processing in Java using BufferedImage

Tags: java, animation, image-processing, colors, bufferedimage

I have encountered a problem while trying to apply a color tint to an animation in java. My code iterates through all the pixels of all the images in the animation (I know it is inefficient, but I want to get it to a working state first). So what it does is, it gets the average of the RGB values of a particular pixel and the tint. It then sets that pixel to the resulting RGB values.

Manually calculating the values result in a pretty good tint(Doing the calculations using a calculator and seeing the color using Google). But unfortunately, when setting the pixels to the calculated RGB. It does not work(Terrible color and far from what should show). I have noticed that when I tried calculating the color and then using that to paint an oval, the results are pretty good. I think that the problem lies the setting the pixel.

```
public void transform(Color color){
//This part just gets the buffered images
        getBuffered();
        for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
            BufferedImage image=catFrames[i];
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                    Color pixelColor = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y), true);
               
                    
                    if(pixelColor.getRGB()==Color.white.getRGB())continue;
                    Color col=new Color((pixelColor.getRed() + color.getRed()) / 2,(pixelColor.getGreen() + color.getGreen()) / 2,(pixelColor.getBlue() + color.getBlue()) / 2,255);
                    
                    image.setRGB(x, y, col.getRGB());
                }
            }
            catFrames[i]=image;
        }
```

This is the method that transforms the individual images into its tinted version.
[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5l59.png)
The oval is what the color should be and the cat is what I'm trying to tint.
Something that might be noteworthy is that coloring when tinting the cat red, it works fine. It does not work when tinting with green and blue.

Also I will not be able to go deeply into image processing, I would appreciate a lot if the solution that would be within the bounds of complexity of what is shown here.

Comment: What is `col`? This variable is not declared anywhere in this method and even worse, not used in the `image.setRGB(x, y, selectedColor.getRGB());` call. And, as a side note, the assignment `catFrames[i]=image;` is obsolete as you’re modifying the image already contained in the array.

Comment: What Holger said.  Your computed color is in `col` but you are setting the pixel using something which is not `col`.

Comment: Sorry as I was debugging and messing around it seems that I forgot to change my code back. But if it is still pertinent, col is a Color instance variable. selectedColor is a public Color instance variable, which my other classes modifies under conditions. After editing, it should all be correct.

Comment: What is the `ColorModel` of the `BufferedImage`s? If they are `IndexColorModel`, chances are they don't have any color matching the one you try to mix. Better convert to a `TYPE_INT_RGB` or similar type image before attempting to change the colors. PS: I tried your logic on the image you linked, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: learn to use the debugger. step through the code. inspect the math. learn about integer overflow. I think that *may* be the cause here. summing two uint8 is bound to overflow in half of all cases.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Java uses signed 32 bit integers for type `int`, with actual values from the code in the range 0-255. So I don't think that's relevant here (well, I know it isn't, as I wrote, it works fine). Agree on the use of a debugger, though! 

Comment: @HaraldK _"I tried your logic on the image you linked, and it seems to work fine"_ What?? How?? The OP's code is looking for the color White (where each component is 0xFF) and adding `+127.5` so I'm not sure how it was "fine" to set an RGB of `( 382.5 , 382.5 , 382.5 )`. If there is overflow going on, then it is correct to get a final grey color (127 or 128). Also I'm not sure how OP got a green color from White either...

Comment: @adekin Define "tint" when you say _"trying to apply a color tint"_ What are you trying to achieve with your shown code? Are you trying to do color **replacement** (_eg:_ change any white pixels into a new target color)? In R-G-B the max of each part is 255. The color White is red=255, grn=255, blu=255 so each part is already at maximum, you cannot add / increase beyond white. PS: Which is more correct? Are you trying to tint as in: **(1)** Take existing colour and add only more white to it? **(1)** Take existing colour and add more R or G or B into it? **(3)** Replace color A with color B?

Comment: @VC.One The linked image has a white background, and no filtering is done on the white color (did you see the `continue`?). I don't see where he adds `127.5` or where you get your numbers from, but each RGB triplet is clearly in the range [0...255]. Adding two numbers between 0 and 255 and diving by two cannot overflow (in Java 32 bit signed integer math as used here). With maximum values this is `(255 + 255) / 2 = 510 / 2 = 255`.

Comment: PS: I never said this was the right way to "tint" images. I just don't think that's the problem the OP is facing.

Comment: @HaraldK I've fixed the screen settings (theme) on my new laptop. I can see properly now the code. Your point is understood. Hopefully you saw the older comments about the numbers 127.5 etc